# WebGL Shader, modify position according to variable

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, webgl, vertex-shader

I'm following the advice in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468192/morphing-a-three-points-object-over-a-period-of-time). I want [this blob to turn into other 3D models](https://www.clicktorelease.com/code/perlin/chrome.html) and back ([like this](https://games.clarklavery.com/meshMorpher/index.html)). This set me on the path of Morphing, but I want to use shaders. The SO post (first link) has a basic run-through of how to do it. I'm currently adapting the example linked in that post to just go from `start position` to `end position` according to the variable `time`. However, either the sprites are not displayed, or they are fixed at the end position. Please take a look and let me know where my logic is off.

Here is a snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - custom attributes [particles]</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info"><a href="https://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> - custom attributes example - particles</div>
        <div id="container"></div>

        <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">

            attribute float size;
            attribute vec3 customColor;
      attribute vec4 endposition;

      uniform float time;

            varying vec3 vColor;

            void main() {

                vColor = customColor;

        vec4 offset = endposition;
        // offset.xyz *= time;

                vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0);

                gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / -mvPosition.z );

                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
        
        gl_Position += offset;
            }

        </script>

        <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">

            uniform vec3 color;
            uniform sampler2D pointTexture;

            varying vec3 vColor;

            void main() {

                gl_FragColor = vec4( color * vColor, 1.0 );
                gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( pointTexture, gl_PointCoord );

            }

        </script>

        <script type="module">

      import * as THREE from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.module.min.js';

      import Stats from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/r17/Stats.min.js';

            let renderer, scene, camera, stats;

            let sphere, material;

            const WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
            const HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 300;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                const amount = 1000;
                const radius = 20;

                const positions = new Float32Array( amount * 3 );
                const colors = new Float32Array( amount * 3 );
                const sizes = new Float32Array( amount );

                const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
                const color = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );

        const endpositions = new Float32Array( amount * 3);
        const endvertex = new THREE.Vector3();
        const endradius = 100;

                for ( let i = 0; i < amount; i ++ ) {

                    vertex.x = ( Math.random() * 2 - 1 ) * radius;
                    vertex.y = ( Math.random() * 2 - 1 ) * radius;
                    vertex.z = ( Math.random() * 2 - 1 ) * radius;
                    vertex.toArray( positions, i * 3 );

          endvertex.x = ( Math.random() * 2 - 1 ) * endradius;
                    endvertex.y = ( Math.random() * 2 - 1 ) * endradius;
                    endvertex.z = ( Math.random() * 2 - 1 ) * endradius;
                    endvertex.toArray( endpositions, i * 3 );

                    if ( vertex.x < 0 ) {

                        color.setHSL( 0.5 + 0.1 * ( i / amount ), 0.7, 0.5 );

                    } else {

                        color.setHSL( 0.0 + 0.1 * ( i / amount ), 0.9, 0.5 );

                    }

                    color.toArray( colors, i * 3 );

                    sizes[ i ] = 10;

                }

                const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
                geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
                geometry.setAttribute( 'customColor', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );
                geometry.setAttribute( 'size', new THREE.BufferAttribute( sizes, 1 ) );
        geometry.setAttribute( 'endposition', new THREE.BufferAttribute( endpositions, 3 ) );

                //

                material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

                    uniforms: {
                        color: { value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) },
                        pointTexture: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31-ijjGFI1L._SY291_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_FMwebp_.jpg" ) },
            time: { type: 'f', value: 0}
                    },
                    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexshader' ).textContent,
                    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentshader' ).textContent,

                    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
                    depthTest: false,
                    transparent: true

                } );

                //

                sphere = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
                scene.add( sphere );

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );

                const container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                stats = new Stats();
                container.appendChild( stats.dom );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();
                stats.update();

            }

            function render() {
                let time = 0

        for (let i = 0; i < 1; i+=0.1) {
          time=i
        }

        material.uniforms.time.value = time;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time variable is not updating, it does if it is in animate() function.

shader:

```
vec3 altposition = mix(position.xyz, endposition.xyz, time);
```

The box exploded like the Death Star here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - custom attributes [particles]</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info"><a href="https://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> - custom attributes example - particles</div>
        <div id="container"></div>

        <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">

            attribute float size;
            attribute vec3 customColor;
      attribute vec4 endposition;

      uniform float time;

            varying vec3 vColor;

            void main() {

                vColor = customColor;

            vec3 altposition = mix(position.xyz, endposition.xyz, time);
        // offset.xyz *= time;

                vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( altposition, 1.0);

                gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / -mvPosition.z );

                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
        
        
            }

        </script>

        <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">

            uniform vec3 color;
            uniform sampler2D pointTexture;

            varying vec3 vColor;

            void main() {

                gl_FragColor = vec4( color * vColor, 1.0 );
                gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( pointTexture, gl_PointCoord );

            }

        </script>

        <script type="module">

      import * as THREE from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.module.min.js';

      import Stats from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/r17/Stats.min.js';

            let renderer, scene, camera, stats;

            let sphere, material;

            const WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
            const HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 300;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                const amount = 1000;
                const radius = 20;

                const positions = new Float32Array( amount * 3 );
                const colors = new Float32Array( amount * 3 );
                const sizes = new Float32Array( amount );

                const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
                const color = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );

        const endpositions = new Float32Array( amount * 3);
        const endvertex = new THREE.Vector3();
        const endradius = 100;

                for ( let i = 0; i < amount; i ++ ) {

                    vertex.x = ( Math.random() * 2 - 1 ) * radius;
                    vertex.y = ( Math.random() * 2 - 1 ) * radius;
                    vertex.z = ( Math.random() * 2 - 1 ) * radius;
                    vertex.toArray( positions, i * 3 );

          endvertex.x = ( Math.random() * 2 - 1 ) * endradius;
                    endvertex.y = ( Math.random() * 2 - 1 ) * endradius;
                    endvertex.z = ( Math.random() * 2 - 1 ) * endradius;
                    endvertex.toArray( endpositions, i * 3 );

                    if ( vertex.x < 0 ) {

                        color.setHSL( 0.5 + 0.1 * ( i / amount ), 0.7, 0.5 );

                    } else {

                        color.setHSL( 0.0 + 0.1 * ( i / amount ), 0.9, 0.5 );

                    }

                    color.toArray( colors, i * 3 );

                    sizes[ i ] = 10;

                }

                const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
                geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
                geometry.setAttribute( 'customColor', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );
                geometry.setAttribute( 'size', new THREE.BufferAttribute( sizes, 1 ) );
        geometry.setAttribute( 'endposition', new THREE.BufferAttribute( endpositions, 3 ) );

                //

                material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

                    uniforms: {
                        color: { value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) },
                        pointTexture: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31-ijjGFI1L._SY291_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_FMwebp_.jpg" ) },
            time: { type: 'f', value: 0}
                    },
                    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexshader' ).textContent,
                    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentshader' ).textContent,

                    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
                    depthTest: false,
                    transparent: true

                } );

                //

                sphere = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
                scene.add( sphere );

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );

                const container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                stats = new Stats();
                container.appendChild( stats.dom );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }
            
            var then = 0;
            var time = -1.633;
      var reverse = 1;
      function animate(now) {
                now *= 0.001;
                
                const delta = now - then;
                
                then = now;
                
                if(time > 15) {
          reverse *= -1;
        }

        if(time < -4) {
          reverse *= -1;
        } 
        
                time = time + delta * 1.0 * reverse;
                material.uniforms.time.value = Math.max(0.0, time);
                
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        
                render();
                stats.update();

            }

        
            function render() {
               

        
        

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why animate() has the `now` argument but is called as `animate()` regardless?

Comment: I stole that part from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45346664